# Redux: Action was successfully dispatched but the State was not created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am just making a simple app to learn Redux. I use the Redux DevTools to see my 2 states: *lists* and *todos*. However it shows only *todos* and although I tried everything I know, it doesn't show *lists*:

Initial State:
[image]

After clicking on the "Add" buttons:
[image]

Here are my codes:

lists.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "lists",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    listAdded: (lists, action) => {
      lists.push({
        id: action.payload.id,
        title: action.payload.title,
        todos: action.payload.todos,
      });
    },
  },
});

export const { listAdded } = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;
```

todos.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "todos",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    todoAdded: (todos, action) => {
      todos.push({
        id: action.payload.id,
        content: action.payload.content,
        check: action.payload.check
      });
    },
    todoEdited: (todos, action) => {
      const index = todos.findIndex((todo) => todo.id === action.payload.id);
      todos[index].content = action.payload.content;
    }
  }
});

export const { todoAdded, todoEdited } = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;
```

reducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import todosReducer from "./todos";
import listsReducer from "./lists";

export default combineReducers({
  lists: listsReducer,
  todos: todosReducer
});
```

configureStore.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import reducer from "./reducer";

const store = () => {
  return configureStore({ reducer });
};

export default store();
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import store from "./configureStore";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

So as you see, it takes the action after I use dispatch. However, because it doesn't have the *state*, when I use *lists.map*, it says *'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'*

What do I do wrong please? Please help! I appreciate it!

*edit: Put more codes related to the Add buttons:*

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ItemTodo from "./ItemTodo";
import ItemList from "./ItemList";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import NewListButton from "./NewListButton";
import NewTodoButton from "./NewTodoButton";

function App() {
  const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todos);
  const lists = useSelector((state) => state.lists);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="todo-list">
        <NewListButton />
        <div>
          {lists.map((item) => (
            <ItemList key={item.id} title={item.title} />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>write a todo</h2>
          {todos.map((item) => (
            <ItemTodo
              key={item.id}
              id={item.id}
              content={item.content}
              check={item.check}
            />
          ))}
          <NewTodoButton />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ItemList.js

```
import React from "react";

const ItemList = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <div className="list-item">
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <div className="list-edit">edit name</div>
      <div className="list-remove">remove list</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemList;
```

ItemTodo.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { todoEdited } from "./todos";

const ItemTodo = ({ id, content, check }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [contentX, setContentX] = useState("");
  const inputTodo = (e) => {
    setContentX(e.target.value);
  };
  const clickEdit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(todoEdited({ id, content: contentX }));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form className="nav-submit">
        <input
          type="text"
          onClick={inputTodo}
          onChange={inputTodo}
          value={contentX}
          onBlur={clickEdit}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemTodo;
```

NewListButton.js

```
import { listAdded } from "./lists";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const NewListButton = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [titleX, setTitleX] = useState("");
  const getListTitle = (e) => {
    setTitleX(e.target.value);
  };
  const setNewList = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const id = uuidv4();
    dispatch(listAdded({ id, title: titleX, todos: [] }));
    setTitleX("");
  };
  return (
    <div className="nav-list">
      <h2>write a list</h2>
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" onChange={getListTitle} value={titleX} />
        <button className="button-newlist" onClick={setNewList}>
          New List
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewListButton;
```

NewTodoButton.js

```
import React from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { todoAdded } from "./todos";

const NewTodoButton = () => {
  const id = uuidv4();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const newTodo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(todoAdded({ id, content: "", check: true }));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button className="button-new" onClick={newTodo}>
        New Todo
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewTodoButton;
```

---

*edit: more info.*

Here is something strange:

I added a file: ListInitialState.js

```
const ListInitialState = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "first list",
    todos: [],
  },
];

export default ListInitialState;
```

then import ListInialState.js to list.js:

```
import ListInitialState from "./ListInitialState";
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "lists",
  initialState: ListInitialState,
  reducers: {
    listAdded: (lists, action) => {
      lists.push({
        id: action.payload.id,
        title: action.payload.title,
        todos: action.payload.todos,
      });
    },
  },
});

export const { listAdded } = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;
```

Finally it worked but I had no idea why:
[image]

It would be great if someone explains it. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Your listsReducer has a default state or not? can you add it in the question?

Comment: @Ashu Sorry what do you mean with it? How to set its state to default?

Comment: Put some code related to add button and triggering the reducer?

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress Sorry I thought those codes were enough to get the state. More codes were added. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't enable redux dev tools.

You can enable redux dev tools with this configuration.

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
})
```

> The Redux DevTools Extension is disabled for production

Comment: Hi, thanks! I tried your code in configureStore.js then "export default store;" but it stays the same like before?

Comment: His todo reducer's state is showing up, so probably it is not about devtools being not connected

Comment: @Ashu Yes, the problem is that the action was successfully dispatched yet the state was never created.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier you were missing the initial state and hence it was not showing up until you dispatched the action, redux in the beginning runs each reducer and those reducers return an initial state which is stored in the store. but I see that in createSlice you did pass an empty array